# React props and states- value doesn't update

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-props

This is a simple react example using props and state. When the user types the name in the given input slot, the name displayed should be updated accordingly in the output section. But the value doesn't update. Can you find the error in the code?

**App.js**

```
import "./App.css";
import UserInput from "./Person/userInput";
import UserOutput from "./Person/userOutput";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    userName: [
      { name: "Max", age: 28, proff: "doctor" },
      { name: "Tom", age: 20, proff: "engg" },
      { name: "Dev", age: 23, proff: "writter" }
    ]
  };

  eHandler = event => {
    this.setState = ({
      userName: [
        { name: event.target.value, age: 28, proff: "doctor" },
        { name: event.target.value, age: 20, proff: "engg" },
        { name: event.target.value, age: 23, proff: "writter" }
      ]
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="card">
          <UserOutput
            name={this.state.userName[0].name}
            age={this.state.userName[0].age}
            proff={this.state.userName[0].proff} 
          />
          <UserInput changed={this.eHandler} />
        </div>
        <div className="card">
          <UserOutput
            name={this.state.userName[1].name}
            age={this.state.userName[1].age}
            proff={this.state.userName[1].proff}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="card">
          <UserOutput
            name={this.state.userName[2].name}
            age={this.state.userName[2].age}
            proff={this.state.userName[2].proff}
          />
          <UserInput changed={this.eHandler} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Component - **userInput.js**

```
const userInput = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={props.changed}></input>
    </div>
  );
};

export default userInput;
```

Component - **userOutput.js**

```
import React from "react";

const userOutput = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        {props.name} of age {props.age} is a {props.proff}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
export default userOutput;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state update in the handler is wrong. It should be the following instead.

```
    this.setState({
      userName: [
        { name: event.target.value, age: 28, proff: "doctor" },
        { name: event.target.value, age: 20, proff: "engg" },
        { name: event.target.value, age: 23, proff: "writter" }
      ]
    });
```

Comment: Yea now it works,thanks! But why wasn't it showing any errors when '=' sign was used?

Comment: Because you actually wrote valid code: You were reassiging the setState property, which is valid javascript. You might have an error if the handler was triggered a second time, as the second time it would not be a function anymore

EDIT: It would not have thrown anything actually, it would just redo the assignment

Comment: ohh.. Is there a efficient way of writting the 'eHandler' code such that only the name of that particular div is updated and not any other divs? open to any other suggestions if not possible!